# Getting bootstraps typeahead functionality to work with database queries in rails

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and javascript and for the life of me can't get this to work. So I'm trying to use bootstraps typeahead to get an autocomplete function but keep hitting obstacles.

So first I try an example from this [site](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/), and everything works nicely. In my `view` I have

```
<input input="text" name="query" id="search" autocomplete="off" />
```

In my `application.js` I have

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require_tree .
```

In my javascript asset folder I have a file called `custom.js` where I dump my javascripts.

In that file I have

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown", "black"];

$('#search').typeahead({source: colors});
```

So now when I open up my view I have a nice textfield with bootstraps `typeahead` functioning.

But I don't want to use a static array to look for values in. I want to access a database column, and look up all values from that column (those values are all unique), and ideally supply the accompanying id to the input field. So I google away and unfortunately try to understand javascript for the first time at the same time.

This question, or a very similar one, has been asked around here a few dozen times, but somehow none of those got my code to work.

Some answers suggested [this](https://gist.github.com/gudbergur/1866577) script, but when I copy the code and save it as `bootstrap-typeahead.js` my normally working js from the `custom.js` file stops working (am I doing that wrong?).

So what I tried was a minimally working solution as suggested on [bootstraps](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) site. The code I'm trying is this in the `custom.js`

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('sources', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }
});
```

and the controller action is like this

```
  def index
    if params[:query]
      @sources = Source.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%"])
    else
      @sources = Source.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|  
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sources }
    end
  end
```

So, here I think I might be at the end of my current capabilities of understanding. When I render my view and type in the input field my console displays

```
Started GET "/sources?query=s" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-06 12:30:10 +0000
Processing by SourcesController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"query"=>"s"}
  Source Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "sources".* FROM "sources" WHERE (name LIKE '%s%')
  Rendered sources/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 194ms (Views: 189.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

So wonderful, my function is calling the right action and the right query... But is it returning anything? Nothing shows up in the input field (there's one record which in the name column has the value KG-01), and how can I see what the json output of the function is? Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs you can see that your request is being handled as HTML and rendering the index, rather than returning JSON.

Try replacing `$.get` with `$.getJSON`.  This will tell jQuery to make a request for JSON, and also parse the JSON result for you:

```
$.getJSON('sources', { query: query }, function (data) {
  // this would print the data to the firefox/chrome javascript console
  console.log(data);

  // the data coming back from your rails action is an array of `Source`
  // records, but typeahead just wants the name.  You could either modify 
  // the server action to just return a list of names, or extract them here.
  var names = data.map(function (source) { return source.name; });

  // Note there is no need to `return` here, as it would be returning from
  // the anonymous callback function, not `source`.
  process(names);
});
```

Comment: Ok, this does not seem to be enough, nothing shows up in the list when typing, the log now displays

    `Started GET "/sources?query=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-06 16:09:18 +0000
    Processing by SourcesController#index as JSON
      Parameters: {"query"=>"1"}
      Source Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "sources".* FROM "sources" WHERE (name LIKE '%1%')
    Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)`

Comment: Is there a quick way possible to just see the json output from the query, just to be sure I'm anticipating the correct data?

Comment: This is proving to insanely helpful, as I said, I'm new to all this, and I did not know about the javascript console. So in my question I mention a boostrap-typeahead.js I saw mentioned but couldn't use, it seems I can't use that since this has been incorporated in the boostrap gem I'm using so i was calling it twice before, right? Anyway, the error I'm getting is: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase' in line 113 of bootstrap-typeahead.js

Comment: I don't think you were calling anything twice.  bootstrap-typeahead.js is the place where the typeahead code lies in bootstrap.  The error suggests that you're passing an object to bootstrap, and looking again at your code, you are.  You don't want to pass all the `Source` objects to process, just the values.

Comment: Absolutely delightful :D So, if I try to understand this correctly: the call to index in the controller returns the object 'source', in the variable 'data'? Then I call a function that maps the source.name .. array? to a js variable called names, which is then processed (into json form, or what exactly does the process function do)? But this works now, this is wonderful!

Comment: Note that the `map` function I use there isn't supported in older browsers (like IE < 9).  If you're targeting those browsers at all you'll need to add it via a script like [augment.js](http://augmentjs.com/) or come up with another way of getting at the names (by your own doing, or something like `_.map` from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/))